# Arduino simulator that allows program custom inputs with code

Tags: simulator

Does anyone know whether there exists simulator that lets you write code that simulates the Arduino inputs?

I need to simulate two microphones connected to Arduino and would prefferably write my own code that uses two PC microphones for that purpose.

So far I've seen that for most emulators you're limited to components delivered by their authors and there is no way to write your own ones or at least custom code for inputs.

Comment: This can be done with [simavr](https://github.com/buserror/simavr), but I have never tried, and it can only work for AVR-based Arduinos.